# Elasticsearch won't find recently inserted data

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I've hit a problem while playing around with ElasticSearch. What I'm trying to do is insert some dummy data and later retrieve it but for some reason, ElasticSearch won't return anything.

Basically what I'm doing is inserting data (unique id, timestamp and object) to index, then I'm waiting for a while (10 seconds) and finally I'm trying to retrieve the inserted record by the unique id (uuid v4) that I generated and checking if the record is not too old (ttl, excluding this check doesn't seem to make difference). But for unknown (for me) reason it just doesn't seem to be working.

I've been banging my head for some time now and I just can't figure out what is wrong. Any help or idea is greatly appreciated.

**Steps to reproduce:**

*Prerequisite software:*

- NodeJS v6.10.1
- ElasticSearch 5.2.1

*Dependencies:*

`npm install uuid bodybuilder elasticsearch`

*test.js*:

```js
var uuid = require('uuid')
var utils = require('util')
var esbuilder = require('bodybuilder')
var Elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')

var client = Elasticsearch.Client({
 "host": "localhost:9200",
 "log": "info",
 "apiVersion": "5.0",
 "requestTimeout": 1000
})

function createIndex (index, structure) {
 return client.indices.create({ index: index, body: structure })
}

function deleteIndex (index) {
 return client.indices.delete({ index: index })
}

function now () {
 return parseInt(Date.now() / 1000)
}

function search (index_name, type, key, ttl) {
 var a = now() - ttl

 var query = esbuilder()
  .filter('term', 'cachekey', key)
  .filter('range', 'created', { gt: a })
  .build()

 var data = {
  index: index_name,
  type: type,
  body: query
 }

 console.log("\r\n#search():", utils.inspect(data, { depth: null }))

 return client.search(data)
}

function save (index_name, type, key, value) {
 var data = {
  index: index_name,
  type: type,
  body: {
   created: now(),
   cachekey: key,
   result: value
  }
 }

 console.log("\r\n#save():", utils.inspect(data, { depth: null }))
 
 return client.index(data)
}


console.log("start")

var index_name = 'whywhywhy'
var structure = {
 mappings: {
  darkside: {
   properties: {
    created: {
     type: 'date'
    },
    cachekey: {
     type: 'string'
    },
    result: {
     type: 'object',
     enabled: false
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

var type_name = 'darkside'
var ttl = 3600 // 5 minutes
var val = { name: 'John', occupation: 'plumber' }
var key = uuid.v4()

createIndex(index_name, structure).then(function (result) {

 console.log("\r\nIndex created: ", utils.inspect(result))

 return save(index_name, type_name, key, val).then(function (result) {
  console.log("\r\nData saved: ", utils.inspect(result))

  console.log("\r\nWaiting for 10 seconds")

  setTimeout(function () {
   return search(index_name, type_name, key, ttl).then(function (result) {

    console.log("\r\nGot this: ", utils.inspect(result))

    setTimeout(function () {
     return deleteIndex(index_name).then(function (result) {
      console.log("\r\nClean up, index deleted: ", utils.inspect(result))
     })
    }, 1500)
   })
  }, 10000)
 })

}).catch(function (err) {

 console.log("\r\nSome fucker failed: ", err)
})
```

*Example Output:*

```
start

Index created:  { acknowledged: true, shards_acknowledged: true }

#save(): { index: 'whywhywhy',
  type: 'darkside',
  body:
   { created: 1491466910,
     cachekey: '55626fcd-9cc9-4ffa-822f-9bebf9652f3d',
     result: { name: 'John', occupation: 'plumber' } } }

Data saved:  { _index: 'whywhywhy',
  _type: 'darkside',
  _id: 'AVtCWvn4O-wYLGwwrqjz',
  _version: 1,
  result: 'created',
  _shards: { total: 2, successful: 1, failed: 0 },
  created: true }

Waiting for 10 seconds

#search(): { index: 'whywhywhy',
  type: 'darkside',
  body:
   { query:
      { bool:
         { filter:
            { bool:
               { must:
                  [ { term: { cachekey: '55626fcd-9cc9-4ffa-822f-9bebf9652f3d' } },
                    { range: { created: { gt: 1491463320 } } } ] } } } } } }

Got this:  { took: 4,
  timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 },
  hits: { total: 0, max_score: null, hits: [] } }

Clean up, index deleted:  { acknowledged: true }
```

Comment: Try to set the type of the `cachekey` field to `keyword` instead of `string`, your UUID has been analyzed and tokenized, hence why you can't find it.

Comment: This is indeed correct. It's also in documentation but in section that did not seem to be relevant for my use case. Guess I was wrong not reading through the whole thing. Thank you, mind also adding it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the data type of the `cachekey` field to `keyword` instead of `string`(or `text`), otherwise your UUID value will get analyzed and tokenized. That's the reason why you can't find it afterwards.

```
var structure = {
    mappings: {
        darkside: {
            properties: {
                created: {
                    type: 'date'
                },
                cachekey: {
                    type: 'keyword'            <--- change this
                },
                result: {
                    type: 'object',
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```